# Conditional rendering with Window in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm working on a simple React app that has opens a new tab with window.open() for a read-only 'presenter' view in which the presenter no longer sees the controlling buttons. It works great, but in my Jest tests when I update the window name the component stays rendered.

Here's the component:

```js
const AdjustTimerButtonGroup = props => {
if (window.name === 'presenter') {
  return null;
}
return(
  //rest of button 
  )
];
```

And here's the test as I currently have it:

```js
  it('does not render if in presenter window', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<AdjustTimerButtonGroup />);
    global.window.name = 'presenter';
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.type()).toEqual(null);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `global` is `window` in jsdom which jest uses. When you are doing `global.window.name` it's essentially like writing `window.window.name`. Try just used `global.name` or `window.name`